# About Yes/No question

Tags: meaning-in-context

The situation is like, I ask someone "Tell me that you're not going to get arrested" and he answers me back a "No, I won't". So in this context, is it usually means "No, I won't give you a word" or "No, I won't get arrested"?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of situations in which we understand the meaning of a response from the context rather than the actual words.

In this situation, people would understand the responder to be saying that he will not get arrested because the other interpretation doesn't make much sense.

Take another example:
**Wouldn't it be lovely if we won the lottery?**

If the answer is **yes**, the literal meaning is that **yes it would not be lovely if we won the lottery**.

But everybody knows from the context that the opposite meaning is intended.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I clearly understand it.